# CoreData sort by expression or select a column as an expression

Tags: ios, core-data

I've got a coreData with sqlite backend of a table with two `NSDate` columns: eventStart and eventEnd. I would like to perform quite a complicated select and sort on it.

For one of the main displays in the application i'd like to retrieve two things:

1. 10 events who's duration (eventEnd - eventStart) was smaller than specified value
2. 10 events who's duration was larger than the specified value
3. The events have to be sorted correctly based on how far from the specified value they are

Two problems i've hit straight away is I can't find a way *select* a column from an expression (the date calculation). The second was `NSSortDescriptor` only seems to work on columns, not expressions. This is contrary to how SQLite works, and i'm wondering if it would be easier to just break out the raw SQL.

I should mention that the data i'm going to be working with will be too large to fit into memory for things like sorting, especially since because the sort is on an expression the query would have to return all data for sorting.

Comment: You should definitely be able to code a qualifier to limit just the 20 rows you're interested in. Which makes me ask how big can those possibly be such that you're not able to sort in a separate statement afterwards? Unless that dynamic sorting value is also part of the predicate, maybe? Just asking because I'm not sure I understand

Comment: the whole dataset is going to be 1000 to 10000 rows hopefully, and the result has to be sorted *before* the limit is applied, just like any 'ol SQL query

Comment: Hmm; possibly look at using NSExpression along with NSDictionaryResultType on the fetch? I'm not sure that's much better, or even gives the result you want, compared to using sqlite directly.

Comment: @wkhatch Is it possible to fire off an SQLite query alongside of coreData without doing the whole song and dance about opening up the database yourself?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. If you're asking whether we can execute raw sql within CoreData, then sadly, no. I wish we could still, like way back when we had EOF. I'd think the NSExpression way might do what you need, though. Have you investigated that? Now I'm curious as to the eventual solution ;-)

Comment: wkhatch, I ended up including the calculated column in my Importer app, but the database grew in size as a result. Sad state of affairs

Comment: Well, it's probably not a bad compromise at worst, given that that approach (which @BlackRider also suggested) solves the hairy query issue. One more column worth of storage shouldn't be too bad, no? Maybe another valid path would be using temp tables during the query so you could just store the values while you need them?

Comment: I'm not sure thats possible with core data. Seen as though you can't do raw sql anymore. It seems that doing anything complicated in coreData would be such a chore. I didn't like adding that extra column just for sorting, especially since the where part worked out ok. I'm reluctant to accept an answer that basically says "No there's no way"

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean using temp tables in a CoreData context; I meant if you were to fall back to using raw sql, as sqlite supports temp tables. You wouldn't have to persist that value beyond the scope of your query and your db size would go back down, etc.

Comment: But then i could just query it with `SELECT eventEnd - eventStart as duration ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I had a very similar problem, I just created a new column for the calculated value (in your case it will be duration). After that, the retrieval becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If you fetch the objects first, you should then be able to sort the result in memory using any key you want, including a method that returns the interval you mentioned. So, you'd create an NSSortDescriptor using the method name that returns this time interval, create a new array  with it, then simply call

```
[originalFetchedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

which will return a new sorted array. If you're starting with an NSMutableArray, you can sort that in place using a similar method.